# Deploy the updated Apex class from Sandbox to Production

Tags: apex, deployment, code-coverage, sandbox, production

I am very new to Salesforce.

I was wondering what is the easiest way to deploy the updated Apex class from Sandbox to Production? I just made some small changes in one of our Apex classes. Since I couldn't modify the class in Production, so I made a Partial Copy Sandbox and edited the Apex class there.

After some physical tests(I didn't write any test file.), it is working good. Now how can I push the updated Apex class to Production?

I searched a bit on google, it seems like I need to download Eclipse, install Force Package, write some test coverage and etc. Do I have any easier way to make it happen?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need any software. Just write your unit test in the sandbox, create a Change Set, add the elements you wish to deploy, upload the Change Set, then log back in to production and make your deployment.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use Change sets. Will need unit test class.
Try following this  -https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/app_deployment/units/app_deployment_changesets if needed